# Error :java: incompatible types: java.sql.ResultSet cannot be converted to java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Im getting error and how to resolve it'loadCostTypes(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>, com.sku.mass.automation.dto.Product)' in 'com.sku.mass.automation.repository.WFRequestRepositoryImpl' cannot be applied to '(java.sql.ResultSet, com.sku.mass.automation.dto.Product)',

```
` @Test
    public void testLoadCostTypes() throws SQLException {
        when(mockResultSet.getString("cost_type_code")).thenReturn("CON");
        when(mockResultSet.getString("cost")).thenReturn("10");
        doReturn(true).when(mockResultSet).next();
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setConCost(12d);
        product.setEdeCost(12d);
        product.setEdhCost(12d);
        product.setEdkCost(12d);
        product.setGovCost(12d);
        product.setPasCost(12d);
        wfRequestRepository.loadCostTypes(mockResultSet, product);
        when(mockResultSet.getString("cost_type_code")).thenReturn("EDE");
        wfRequestRepository.loadCostTypes(mockResultSet, product);
        when(mockResultSet.getString("cost_type_code")).thenReturn("EDH");
        wfRequestRepository.loadCostTypes(mockResultSet, product);
        when(mockResultSet.getString("cost_type_code")).thenReturn("PAD");
        wfRequestRepository.loadCostTypes(mockResultSet, product);
        when(mockResultSet.getString("cost_type_code")).thenReturn("EDK");
        wfRequestRepository.loadCostTypes(mockResultSet, product);
        when(mockResultSet.getString("cost_type_code")).thenReturn("GSA");
        wfRequestRepository.loadCostTypes(mockResultSet, product);
        when(mockResultSet.getString("cost_type_code")).thenReturn("GOV");
        wfRequestRepository.loadCostTypes(mockResultSet, product);
        Assertions.assertTrue(true);

    }
`
```

```
 public void loadCostTypes(Map<String, String> rs , Product product) throws SQLException {  //NOSONAR
        Double margin = null;
        if (rs != null ) {
            String costType = rs.get("cost_type_code");

            if (costType != null && costType.equals("CON")) {
                product.setConCost(Double.valueOf(rs.get("cost")));
                margin = calculateMargin(product.getFixedPrice(), product.getConCost(), margin);
            } else if (costType != null && costType.equals("EDE")) {
                product.setEdeCost(Double.valueOf(rs.get("cost")));
                margin = calculateMargin(product.getFixedPrice(), product.getEdeCost(), margin);
            } else if (costType != null && costType.equals("EDH")) {
                product.setEdhCost(Double.valueOf(rs.get("cost")));
                margin = calculateMargin(product.getFixedPrice(), product.getEdhCost(), margin);
            } else if (costType != null && costType.equals("PAD")) {
                product.setPasCost(Double.valueOf(rs.get("cost")));
                margin = calculateMargin(product.getFixedPrice(), product.getPasCost(), margin);
            } else if (costType != null && costType.equals("EDK")) {
                product.setEdkCost(Double.valueOf(rs.get("cost")));
                margin = calculateMargin(product.getFixedPrice(), product.getEdkCost(), margin);
            } else if (costType != null && costType.equals("GSA")) {
                product.setGsaCost(Double.valueOf(rs.get("cost")));
                margin = calculateMargin(product.getFixedPrice(), product.getGsaCost(), margin);
            } else if (costType != null && costType.equals("GOV")) {
                product.setGovCost(Double.valueOf(rs.get("cost")));
                margin = calculateMargin(product.getFixedPrice(), product.getGovCost(), margin);
            }
        }
        if (margin != null) {
            product.setMargin( BigDecimal.valueOf(margin));
            log.info("Margin Caluclated in product bean is {} ", product.getMargin());
        }
    }
```

i have fixed the code as attached and does this code looks clean now

```
public void testLoadCostTypes() throws SQLException {

    Map<String, String> mockResultSet1 = resultSetToMap("CON", "10");

    Product product = new Product();
    product.setConCost(12d);
    product.setEdeCost(12d);
    product.setEdhCost(12d);
    product.setEdkCost(12d);
    product.setGovCost(12d);
    product.setPasCost(12d);
    wfRequestRepository.loadCostTypes(mockResultSet1, product);

    // Setup behavior for subsequent calls
    Map<String, String> mockResultSet2 = resultSetToMap("EDE", "15");


    wfRequestRepository.loadCostTypes(mockResultSet2, product);
    // Setup behavior for subsequent calls
    Map<String, String> mockResultSet3 = resultSetToMap("EDH", "15");

    wfRequestRepository.loadCostTypes(mockResultSet3, product);
    // Setup behavior for subsequent calls
    Map<String, String> mockResultSet4 = resultSetToMap("PAD", "15");

    wfRequestRepository.loadCostTypes(mockResultSet4, product);
    // Setup behavior for subsequent calls
    Map<String, String> mockResultSet5 = resultSetToMap("EDK", "15");

    wfRequestRepository.loadCostTypes(mockResultSet5, product);
    // Setup behavior for subsequent calls
    Map<String, String> mockResultSet6 = resultSetToMap("GSA", "15");

    wfRequestRepository.loadCostTypes(mockResultSet6, product);
    // Setup behavior for subsequent calls
    Map<String, String> mockResultSet7 = resultSetToMap("GOV", "15");

    wfRequestRepository.loadCostTypes(mockResultSet7, product);
    Assertions.assertTrue(true);

}
```

Comment: The error looks self-explanatory, `resultset` object is of type `java.sql.ResultSet` but the method `loadCostTypes` expects the first Parameter to be of type `java.util.Map`.

Comment: unrelated, but still, if you want to keep your code a bit more clean, use: if ( "STRING_LITERAL".equals(stringVariable) ) instead of adding nullchecks in every if statement

Comment: i have fixed the error as attached but not really sure if this will keep my code clean